# How do i stop my service?

Tags: android

i have a service which shows a toast message. i defined it in manifest like this-

```
 <service android:name=".ShowNotification" />
```

and this is my service-

```
public class ShowNotification extends Service {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "service worked once",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

but i cannot figure out how to stop this service and also how to start it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

`stopService(new Intent(this, ShowNotification.class));`

`startService(new Intent(this, ShowNotification.class));`

And restart the Service, gona recall `onCreate()`

Comment: hey, just a simple question, if i start my service, the code in the oncreate of my service will be called only once right? until i start it again

Comment: your code is not working, i started my service from oncreate of my class using startService(new Intent("ShowNotification")); but i see no toast

Comment: No, don't start like that. `startService(new Intent(this, ShowNotification.class)`.

Comment: I just edit my answer. Tell me if you stil have some error.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) rather than using only Service. IntentService will be destroyed automatically after completion of the task.You don't need to worry about stopping it.